# Issue with Threads/sockets and MySql (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, sockets

I have a big problem with an exercise from my java teacher.
In theory the exercise must have the following points:

-Sockets 
-Clients
-Server
-The server uses MySql for something 
-Login
-Md5 to save the passwords
-Secure socket

With this I decide to make a chat in theory should be easy stuff but... I'm completely lose.

More or less I made the basic (Secure Socket, server, clients) but even that doesn't work, but the IDE makes no fail in theory should be fine.

Someone May help me?

The code is just below:

ChatClient this make work the client, loading the interface and the features:

```
public class ChatClient 
{


    private Socket s;

    private ClientPanel panel;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new ChatClient();
    }

    public ChatClient()
    {
        try
        {
            Window();
            s = new Socket("localhost" , 5557);
            ClientControl control = new ClientControl(s, panel);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void Window()
    {
        JFrame v = new JFrame();
        panel = new PanelCliente(v.getContentPane());
        v.pack();
        v.setVisible(true);
        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

ServerChat this create a server chat with secure sockets as one of the requisites of the exercise:

```
public class ServerChat extends Thread
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            int port= 5090;

            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserver = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            try 
            {
                SSLServerSocket sslsocket = (SSLServerSocket)sslserver.createServerSocket();

                InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost" , port);

                while(true)
                    {

                        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)sslsocket.accept();
                        System.out.println("Client:  " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName() + " Conected");

                    }   
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           

    }

}


public class ClientControl implements ActionListener, Runnable
{

    private DataInputStream dataInput;

    private DataOutputStream dataOutput;

    private ClientPanel panel;

    public ClientControl (Socket s, ClientPanel panel)
    {
        this.panel = panel;

        try
        {
            dataInput = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            panel.addActionListener(this);
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        try
        {
            dataOutput.writeUTF(panel.getTexto());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String text = dataInput.readUTF();
            panel.addTexto(text);
            panel.addTexto("\n");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Client Thread in theory this make posible to run the client as a thread and implements it's functions:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable, ListDataListener
{

    private DefaultListModel conversation;

    private Socket s;

    private DataInputStream dataInput;

    private DataOutputStream dataOutput;

    public ClientThread (DefaultListModel conversation, Socket s)
    {
        this.conversation = conversation;
        this.s = s;

        try
        {
            dataInput = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            conversation.addListDataListener(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                String text = dataInput.readUTF();
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e)
    {
        String text = (String) conversation.getElementAt(e.getIndex0());

        try
        {
            dataOutput.writeUTF(text);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent arg0) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent arg0) 
    {   
    }
}
```

Client Panel is below basically makes a simple design with JSwing to create and interface where you see the conversation and you can writte whatever you want:

```
public class ClientPanel
{

    private JScrollPane scroll;

    private JTextArea textArea;

    private JTextField textField;

    private JButton button;


    public ClientPanel(Container cont)
    {
        cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        textField = new JTextField(50);
        button = new JButton("Send");
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(button);

        cont.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cont.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void addActionListener (ActionListener action)
    {
        textField.addActionListener(action);
        button.addActionListener(action);
    }

    public void addTexto (String text)
    {
        textArea.append(text);
    }

    public String getTexto()
    {
        String text = textField.getText();
        textField.setText(text);
        return text;
    }
}
```

How can I add a database to Log in users?
How can I add there Md5 to protect the passwords?
How can I make this all work together?

That's my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a server and clients and want to write a chat. So the server is the center and holds the connection to the database where all persistent data is stored. The password is not stored as plain text, only it's md5 hash is stored in database. 
Furthermore, only the server holds a connection to the database.

This answers where to use `MD5` and which guy the master of the database is.

You have already created a `SeverChat`. That guy is responsible to listen for new clients to connect. If a new client wants to connect, the `ServerChat` has to spawn a new `ClientController`.

Your `ClientControl` does not look like what I mean. A `ClientControll` is responsible to take the request from the specific client he is connect to, handle the request and send an answer to the client.

That means you need some sort of a protokol. You can use [ObjectStreams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html) to send objects from the client to the sever and vice versa. 
This makes it easier to define a protokol.

To get an idea of the `ClientController`:

```
  class ClientController extends Thread {

    private final ObjectInputStream dataInput;
    private final ObjectOutputStream dataOutput;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;

    ClientController(ObjectInputStream dataInput, ObjectOutputStream dataOutput) {
      this.dataInput = dataInput;
      this.dataOutput = dataOutput;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        boolean stayConnected = true;
        while (stayConnected) {
          Object data = dataInput.readObject();
          if (data instanceof LoginAction) {
//          check data an do login
            this.loggedIn = true;
            dataOutput.write(new LoginResponse(/* response data */));
          }
          if (data instanceof RequestChatDataAction) {
            if (this.loggedIn) {
              dataOutput.write(new NotLoggedInResponse());
            } else {
              dataOutput.write(new ChatDataResponse(/* chat data.. */));
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

The `LoginAction`, `LoginResponse` a.s.o. objects define your protokol. You need of cause more objects to implement all features and these objects have to implement `java.io.Serializable`. Otherwise, you will not be able to send them over the wire.

You have to write counter part as well - the client.

The client starts up, connects to the server and tries to login. If login is successfull, the client waits for new chat data and displays it. 
If the user types in something, this data is send to the server and will be added to the 'gobal' chat data.

I would recommend not to add the gui elements before the client-server communication is done. You can use the `System.out` and `System.in` to interact with the user.

So, I hope that helps you.

Furthermore, SO is not for questions like: Do my homework. I see that you already have taken the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be appreciated.

Comment: Up vote my answer would be appreciated if it was helpful to you.